# События - асинхронны? Как затормозить обработчик события так, чтобы не остановить все остальное?

Tags: c#, события, асинхронность, task

У меня есть два класса, которые общаются с помощью событий.
Обработчик события в классе Bot, которое приходит из внешнего источника:

```
        private void OnOrder(Order order)
        {
            if (order.Account == Tool.AccountID && order.SecCode == Tool.SecurityCode && order.State == State.Completed) 
            {
                Task.Delay(50); // здесь нужно подождать 
                Strategy.ProcessingExecutedOrders(order);
            }
        }
```

Метод в классе Bot, в котором вызывается событие NewDeal:

```
private void SendOrders(ref Deal deal)
        {
              // что-то происходит
              // асинхронный метод, после которого может прийти событие OnOrder, а может и не прийти
              temp_order = QuikConnecting.LimitOrder(Tool, deal.OrdersInfo[i].Operation, deal.OrdersInfo[i].Price, deal.OrdersInfo[i].Vol).Result; 
              if (temp_order != null)
              {
                   deal.OrdersInfo[i].IDOrder = temp_order.OrderNum;
                   deal.OrdersInfo[i].IssueStatus = State.Completed;
                   deal.Status = StatusDeal.Open;
                   NewDeal?.Invoke(deal, Command.SendOrder); // вызываю другое событие, которое передает объект в другой класс
              }
              // что-то происходит
        }
```

Проблема в том, что событие OnOrder может прийти раньше, чем произойдет NewDeal?.Invoke. И мне нужно чтобы OnOrder ждал хоть какое-то время, но Task.Delay не работает.
В связи с этим вопрос, как тормознуть обработчик события OnOrder так, чтобы метод SendOrders продолжил работать?

Comment: Если в вашей системе из двух классов порядок независимых друг от друга событий начал играть роль и вы начали добавлять какие то тайминги в код, то вы что то явно делаете не так. Никаких таймингов в коде в идеале быть не должно, а все события, если они возникают независимо друг от друга, то и обрабатываться они должны независимо. По вашим двум фрагментам кода советовать нечего, так как этого недостаточно даже для понимания вашей проблемы.

Comment: Чую, тут либо таски нужны, либо очередь. Но без знания конкретики сложно понять. Первым делом надо диаграмму рисовать - что у вас там происходит и в каком порядке. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Вот эту цитату от @tym32167 надо высечь в камне.*

> Если в вашей системе из двух классов порядок независимых друг от друга событий начал играть роль и вы начали добавлять какие то тайминги в код, то вы что то явно делаете не так.

---

Если вопрос только про ожидание, то у вас всего 2 опции ожидания:

1. Синхронное

```cs
private void OnOrderAsync(Order order)
{
    if (order.Account == Tool.AccountID && order.SecCode == Tool.SecurityCode && order.State == State.Completed) 
    {
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        Strategy.ProcessingExecutedOrders(order);
    }
}
```

2. Асинхронное

```cs
private async Task OnOrder(Order order)
{
    if (order.Account == Tool.AccountID && order.SecCode == Tool.SecurityCode && order.State == State.Completed) 
    {
        await Task.Delay(50);
        Strategy.ProcessingExecutedOrders(order);
    }
}
```

Разница в том, что первое блокирует вызывающий поток на время ожидания, в второе - нет.

Как вы уже наверное поняли, вы просто неправильно использовали `Task.Delay`.

---

Так же у вас ошибка в использовании асинхронной операции, вы ее вызываете синхронно, что в принципе противоречит принципам асинхронности

```cs
// делаем метод асинхронным - вызывать так: await SendOrdersAsync(...);
private async Task SendOrdersAsync(ref Deal deal)
{
    // ...
    temp_order = await QuikConnecting.LimitOrder(Tool, deal.OrdersInfo[i].Operation, deal.OrdersInfo[i].Price, deal.OrdersInfo[i].Vol); 
    if (temp_order != null)
    {
        deal.OrdersInfo[i].IDOrder = temp_order.OrderNum;
        deal.OrdersInfo[i].IssueStatus = State.Completed;
        deal.Status = StatusDeal.Open;
        NewDeal?.Invoke(deal, Command.SendOrder);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Никогда не используйте `.Wait()` или `.Result` для асинхронных операций. Это ошибка, которая 1) вешает вам поток, 2) может привести к взаимоблокировке потоков - дедлоку.

Неисключено, что после того как вы поправите ошибку вызова асинхронного метода, ваши события заработают как надо, и не придется втыкать костыли типа `Task.Delay`.

Почитайте: [Асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async).

Comment: Интересно, будет ли оно рельно ждать 50 миллисекунд здесь `await Task.Delay(50);` - сдается мне что просто операция переключения контекста может скушать примерно столько же (ну или что то сопоставимое с 50 мс). Это не относится к вопросу или ответу, чисто интерес. Когда нибудь гляну в исходники поковырять :)

Comment: @tym32167 ну будет ждать точно не меньше, чем 50мс. У меня в тестах если при начале ожидания был задействован спавн нового потока, то оно обычно выливалось в ~30мс, во всех остальных случаях 1-2мс.

Comment: Я просто припоминаю, что вроде где то писали о том, что некоторые асинхронные операции работают по slim методу. То есть если операция завершилась очень быстро, то она считай выполнена синхронно, если же какой то порог времени прошел, то тогда выполнена будет асинхронно. Но это просто какие то отпечатки у меня в памяти, уже не помню про что конкретно там писали.

Comment: @tym32167 проверить просто - если континуация с использованием `.ConfigureAwait(false)` пошла в том же потоке, значит операция была выполнена синхронно. Быть может есть нюансы, но по-моему это 100% индикатор. А вообще народ уже вовсю балется с `ValueTask` и считает синхронное завершение нормальным делом, когда ждать не надо, при этом по аллокациям влезая полностью в стек.

Comment: Я что то слышал про `ValueTask`, но не глядел не этого зверя. Чую, ещё пару-тройку лет и если я захочу вернуться в C# обратно, то мне придется учить его заново :)

Comment: @tym32167 вот прямо [с этого и начать](https://habr.com/ru/post/458828/), тема суперпростая. Я правда читал в оригинале в блоге (ссылка там есть), но для вас даже нашел перевод. :) Еще ключевые штуки из нового - `Span<T>` и `ArrayPool<T>`, ну и конечно же божественный и быстрый `Channel` из `System.Threading.Channels` (async producer/consumer). Остальные новинки типа `record`, как по мне - мелочи.

Comment: Спасибо! Гляну на досуге.